# Local Video have a Sound in background after leaving view controller

Tags: swift

I want to play a local video in a frame not fullscreen, the video will play but when I go to the next view controller by pressing a button ,the video's sound will continue in background ,and here is my code, can anyone help me how to stop video's sound? thanks

```
 playVideo()
              }

              private func playVideo() {
                  guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType:"mp4") else {
                      debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
                      return
                  }
                  let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                  let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                  playerController.player = player



                          let controller=AVPlayerViewController()
                          controller.player=player
                          controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 40, width: self.view.bounds.width - 2, height: 280)
                          self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
                          self.addChild(controller)
                          player.play()
```